# Is there a more efficient way to delete elements from a dictionary?

Tags: python

```
d = {'a1':1, 'a2':2,'a3':3,'a4':1,'a5':1,'b':2, 'c':3}

for k, v in d.copy().items():
    if 'a' in k:
        del d[k]

print(d)
```

I want to delete elements if the key or value meets a certain requirement, as above, in which the keys containing 'a' will be deleted.

In particular, can I somehow not use the copy() function to do the same thing?

EDIT: Based on suggestion, I adopted this way:

```
for k in list(d):
    if 'a' in k:
        del d[k]
```

Comment: You don't have to copy the entire `dict`, just the keys: `for k in list(d): ...`

Comment: you need to use `del`  in a dict if you want to remove key-value pair from dicionary without rewriting it all

Comment: @mozway A `del` solution after all... Did you realize that none of the answers under the question which you claim this duplicates have a `del` solution?

Comment: If just iterating through the keys, I can just do 'for k in d:'. Why should I do list(d)?

Comment: @marlon try without it ;)

Comment: Yes, it won't work. Just tried. @mozway

Comment: what's about using .pop?

Comment: @Kelly then I think OP already had the answer, I just provided a minor variant

Comment: @mozway What answer had they had already? I.e., what more efficient than their own code had they already had? (I'm btw not at all convinced that yours is more efficient.)

Comment: I never said it was, just fits in one line, iterating over `list(d)` is likely better ;)

Comment: @mozway A Python function call per element is not good, though.

Comment: @mozway [Theirs 4.7 ms, yours 7.7 ms](https://tio.run/##XVDJasMwEL3rK@YWqRXGJpdiyJeEYmR75AyxFiS1iVv67a7lBUp1EXrbjJ6f0s3Z85sP86yDMxBTIDsAGe9CAhU7omZ0Dwydiri8QbUdW5VB2X65dmV3c9ShXFGyifVwge8N5ItFwGuO5jvNKwlVWZZC1PAfAu0CNEA2MwPyDJbih/mQVSNa3gvBWI8aXKCBrBq5qBmsvruEz2zti875iYuCEpq48QCk4aROmb9vQD5exbjFGff1UNOfsKzUNCYMfFSm7RU86yPhKWGkmPIy9Z6x1pLIIKWjloAeVWI5TWfX9VhZ7tPe4QXOeWBaCjNk@ebgWoL9MC2GS7W0tPDb95MEXTSNVQabRszzLw).

Comment: @Kelly and? I never claimed faster speed, at most shorter code

Comment: @mozway The question doesn't ask for shorter, it asks for more efficient. So you're saying your comment had nothing to do with the question? Usually when people post solutions, they're meant to address the question, that's why I thought you meant it's more efficient.

Comment: I just provided an alternative, not sure why you're obsessed about it. If you wanted to do an interesting comparison, you should have included `list(d)`.

Comment: Not realized that different ways' performance differ big. If they are called in a loop, that could be a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new dictionary without the key you want to filter

```py
d = {'a1':1, 'a2':2,'a3':3,'a4':1,'a5':1,'b':2, 'c':3}

filtered_d = {k: v for k,v in d.items() if 'a' not in k}
```

Comment: Sometimes, you really do just want to remove items from an existing `dict`, rather than create a new restricted `dict`.

Comment: @chepner I tested using the `for k in list(d)` loop with `del` and the dictionary comprehension i proposed here, each on a 10 milions random keys dictionnary. For both, i got a time of that about `0.3` ms.

Comment: Time isn't the issue; it's whether the dict needs to be modified in-place because some one else is holding a reference to the same object and expects to see the results.

Comment: I accepted this answer but in my code I chose the in-place modification approach by using list(d), which seems better.